# SAS SQL Conditional Group By

Tags: sql, group-by, sas, conditional-statements

I need to sum the values in var_x where the values of date_y are between date_y and date_y - 90 (days), also grouped by Acc_ID .

For example

```
Acc_ID  date_y      var_x
1        01Jan2019   1
1        15Nov2019   2
1        01Dec2019   3
2        01Aug2018   1
2        12Aug2018   2
2        30Jun2019   3
2        05Jul2019   4
```

The output should be:

```
Acc_ID  date_y      var_x    sum_z
1        01Jan2019   1        1
1        15Nov2019   2        2
1        01Dec2019   3        5
2        01Aug2018   1        1
2        12Aug2018   2        3
2        30Jun2019   3        3
2        05Jul2019   4        7
```

I'm working with a SAS dataset and can't come up with a simple way.

I considered using SUMIFS in Excel but I'm dealing with ~2.5 million records so it's a bit impractical. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56467599/looking-back-in-sas/56507147#56507147 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47553143/calculate-rolling-sum-for-one-column-in-time-interval-in-sas/47559567#47559567

Comment: Please remember to show what you've tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in `proc sql`.  One method uses a correlated subquery:

```
proc sql;
    select t.*,
           (select sum(t2.var_x)
            from t t2
            where t2.acc_id = t.acc_id and
                  (t.date_y - t2.date_y) between 0 and 90
    from t;
quit;
```

You can also express this as an explicit `JOIN`:

```
proc sql;
    select t.acc_id, t.date_y, t.var_x,
           sum(t2.var_x)
    from t join
         t t2
         on t2.acc_id = t.acc_id and
            (t.date_y - t2.date_y) between 0 and 90
    group by t.acc_id, t.date_y, t.var_x;
quit;
```

In more powerful databases, you can use window functions for the same purpose.  But that would only be helpful for pass-through SQL.

Answer (score 2):

Here are four ways:

- SQL: self left join with a DISTINCT selection
- SQL: select with correlated sub-query
- Data Step: one pass with sum over all values stored in domain ring-array (modulus index)
- Data Step: one pass with out/in sum of values stored in domain ring-array (modulus index)

The fastest is the last, but the sums *might* experience accumulated round off errors if the summed values are not integers.

```
data have;
  do id = 1 to 10;
    do date = '01jan2018'd to '31dec2018'd;
      x = floor(100*ranuni(123));
      date + floor(30*ranuni(123));
      output;
    end;
  end;
  format date yymmdd10.;
run;

proc sql;
  * version 1 with DISTINCT;

  create table want1 as
  select distinct
    self.id, self.date, self.x, sum(each.x) as x_sum_90
  from
    have as self
  left join
    have as each
  on
    self.id = each.id and
    each.date between self.date and self.date-90
  group by 
    self.id, self.date
  ;

  * version 2 with correlated SUB SELECT;

  create table want2 as
  select distinct
    self.id, self.date, self.x,
    (select sum(each.x) from have as each where 
     self.id = each.id and
     each.date between self.date and self.date-90
    ) as x_sum_90
  from
    have as self
  ;
quit;

proc compare noprint base=want1 compare=want2 out=diff outNoEqual;
run;

* version 3. DOW loop with sum over rolling domain;
* presumes no duplicate dates;

data want3;
  array domainDate[0:89] _temporary_;
  array domainValu[0:89] _temporary_;

  _tail = 0;
  _head = 0;

  call missing (of domainDate[*]);
  call missing (of domainValu[*]);

  domainDate[0] = 0;
  domainValu[0] = 0;

  do until (last.id) ;
    set have;
    by id;

    _head = mod(_head+1,90);
    do while (domainDate[_tail] < date-90 and _tail ne _head);
      domainValu[_tail] = 0;
      _tail = mod(_tail+1, 90);
    end;

    domainValu[_head] = x;
    domainDate[_head] = date;

    x_sum_90 = sum(of domainValu[*]);
    output;
  end;
  drop _:;
run;

proc compare noprint base=want2 compare=want3 out=diff outNoEqual;
run;

* version 4. DOW loop with in-out 'point-of-reckoning' arithmetic (roundoff may occur with decimal parted values);
* presumes no duplicate dates;

data want4;
  array domainDate[0:89] _temporary_;
  array domainValu[0:89] _temporary_;

  _tail = 0;
  _head = 0;

  call missing (of domainDate[*]);
  call missing (of domainValu[*]);

  domainDate[0] = 0;
  domainValu[0] = 0;

  do until (last.id) ;
    set have;
    by id;

    _head = mod(_head+1,90);
    do while (domainDate[_tail] < date-90 and _tail ne _head);
      x_sum_90 = sum (x_sum_90, -domainValu[_tail]); * out with the old;
      _tail = mod(_tail+1, 90);
    end;

    domainValu[_head] = x;
    domainDate[_head] = date;

    x_sum_90 = sum(x_sum_90, x); * in with the new;
    output;
  end;
  drop _:;
run;

proc compare noprint base=want3 compare=want4 out=diff outNoEqual;
run;
```

Comment: NOTE: The difference between my `DISTINCT` version and @Gordon Linoff explicit `JOIN` is that his `group by` is deeper and includes `x`.  My `group by` stops at `date`